# create percentage and ratio in r

Tags: r, dplyr

My original dataset is

```
group value
a     na
b     1
c     1
c     3
d     2
d     3
```

I want to a new dataset with two new variables - percentage and ratio

```
group value percent(%) ratio
a     na    na      na
b     1     0       0
c     1     200     3
d     2     50       3/2 =1.5
```

Can I use dplyr package to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. In the following example, `dt4` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- data_frame(group = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
                 value = c(NA, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3))

dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n() == 2) %>%
  summarise(Value = first(value),
            `percent(%)` = (last(value) - first(value))/first(value) * 100, 
            ratio = last(value)/first(value)) %>%
  rename(value = Value)

dt3 <- dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  filter(n() == 1) %>%
  mutate(`percent(%)` = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, 0),
         ratio = ifelse(is.na(value), NA, 0))

dt4 <- dt2 %>%
  bind_rows(dt3) %>%
  arrange(group)
```